# How to make logger to ignore empty messages in java

Tags: java, logging

i see logs which are empty. Is there a way to avoid lines with empty logging ?

2014-10-28 06:00:00 -

2014-10-28 06:00:00 -

2014-10-28 06:00:00 - B;ah Blah!

Comment: Instead of checking content isEmpty, alternate way to do

Comment: What logging tool are you using? There's not enough information here.